# How to configure getting statsd performance metrics into graphite?

Tags: monitoring, graphite, statsd

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29624380/unknown-number-of-metrics-received-with-statsd-and-graphite) mentions two types of performance stats:

1. `carbon.*`: Stats from graphite itself.
2. `stats.*` : Stats from statsd.

I am seeing 1., but I'm not seeing 2.
Is there a statsd configuration setting (e.g. some entry in the js file) which will let me see 2.?

Answer (score 0):

(2) should be generated by default, but the default prefix is `statsd.` and not `stats.` as you've said.  Maybe check that you don't have any Graphite rules expecting the wrong prefix.

You can also configure the prefix to whatever you want using the `prefixStats` property in the .js config file.

See the documentation in the example config:
https://github.com/etsy/statsd/blob/master/exampleConfig.js